# EntitySet schema value dbo instead of database.dbo

Tags: entity-framework, entity, entityset

Running EFProfiler found that the query running behind the scenes was

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Total] AS [Total]
FROM  [dbo].[Invoice] AS [Extent1]
```

The problem is that the DB name is incorrect. It should be:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Total] AS [Total]
FROM  [Chinook].[dbo].[Invoice] AS [Extent1]
```

How do I change the syntax of entityset schema ?

```
<EntitySet Name="Invoice" EntityType="ChinookModel.Store.Invoice" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
```

I have tried changing the schema to `Chinook.dbo`, but it does not work.

Comment: You'll need to use the {} button on the editor to markup your code when you ask questions otherwise it won't display correctly.

Comment: You can only set the database name in the connection string, not in the designer. And it won't show up in the query.

Comment: The name is there in the connection string, it works well in visual studio 2010, I am doing the same in VS2012 its not working